# Restricting Solr Data if no pageSize is provided

Tags: solr

Currently wcf service returns 10 Million records from solr when queried  and no page size is specified.
How can i change the default page/row size when no page size is specified? Where is this setting that it gets 10 Million data by default?

Comment: try to updates the `ContentSearch.SearchMaxResults` setting value, you can find this setting in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.config` for Sitecore 9.3.

Comment: I am using a WCF service and using Solrnet.dll to connect to Solr . How do i update there?

Answer (score 1):

You can add default parameters in **solrconfig.xml** in *requestHandler* of your index.

For example, if you want to limit default rows count by 10, you just need to add:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
       <int name="rows">10</int>
   </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

In this case, if your query does not have `rows` parameter, `rows=10` will be added.